# Atomically select two tables in Linq-to-SQL

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq-to-sql

I am using Linq-to-SQL and I have a situation where I am trying to update my entites with `Refresh` method of `DataContext`.

I am refreshing two tables, but there is also a procedure that can modify one of a tables. The data in those two tables has to be synchronized.

The problem is that sometimes can happen that I refresh one table, stored procedure changes both tables at that moment and I refresh the second table which is no longer synchronized with the other.

How can I make sure that when I refresh two tables in Linq-to-SQL nothing can happen to any of them?

Transaction would lock table as soon as it gets to selecting the table, so it won't guarantee that after selecting first table, second won't get modified.

Code example:

```
_dc.Refresh(RefreshMode.KeepChanges, _dc.Table1);
// here Table2 might be changed by procedure, I need to prevent it
_dc.Refresh(RefreshMode.KeepChanges, _dc.Table2);
```

Comment: A select inside a transaction would only place a shared (S) lock on the table - and only for the duration of the actual reading of the data (in the default isolation level) - that won't stop the "other" party from updating, I believe....

Comment: @marc_s So the only way is to move this selection to stored procedure?

Comment: No - you could investigate isolation levels (those change the behavior of how long a shared lock is kept), or you could select with hints like `XLOCK` (exclusive lock) and `HOLDLOCK` (hold on to the lock)

Comment: I wouldn't worry about the refreshing  because the server should automatically do the locking.  I would worry about creating new Primary Keys.  When a database is shared you must create Primary keys in a stored procedure so duplicates keys are not created by two different users.